# 404 error on ssl for part of site

Tags: nginx, configuration

Im trying to force /register as https, but I'm getting an error 404, nothing is wrong with the certicate as previously I had the entire domain under ssl.

Here's my conf, where am I going wrong?

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;
root /var/www/example.com/site/public;

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp-error.log error;

sendfile off;

client_max_body_size 100m;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
location /register{
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
}



server{
   listen 443;
   root /var/www/example.com/site/public;   
   location / {
    return 301  http://www.example.com$request_uri;
   }
   location /register {
   }
   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/cert_chain.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com/server.key;
    }
```

Comment: Show us the errors from your log file.

Comment: Log file states: 2015/10/05 10:16:29 [error] 2844#0: *1 open() "/var/www/example.com/site/public/register" failed (2: No such file or directory)